# Word como base para um relatório em delphi que tem detail

Tags: delphi, relatório, microsoft-word

Galera tenho um documento word padrão usado na empresa para fazer uma lista de presença em treinamentos, porém agora eles querem gerar essa lista, com os nomes dos participantes, já preenchida através do sistema em delphi 6. 
Vi aqui no forum como incluir dados de campos no word, mas no meu caso além de alguns que só precisam ser inseridos uma vez, como a maioria dos exemplos dados aqui (contrato, ficha de alguma coisa), tenho o detail, isso é, todos os participantes do treinamento. 
Preciso que alguns campos sejam preenchidos apenas uma vez, nome do treinamento, data e instrutor, mas preciso que de alguma forma um loop preencha o detail. 
Alguém pode me ajudar? É meio urgente.

Answer (score 1):

Vou explicar seguindo a lógica de raciocínio como se estivéssemos desenvolvendo do zero uma impressão no Word.

**Primeiro:** Tenha um modelo do relatório em Word, talvez você o colocando como um `resource` da aplicação te garanta uma segurança melhor para evitar que o mesmo seja alterado por terceiro (como se ele fosse um arquivo estático).

**Segundo:** Utilize variáveis do tipo `variant` para instanciar o objeto do Word, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
uses Word2000, ComObj;

function CriarObjetoWord(out pObjWord: variant): boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  try 
    pObjWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
    Result := True; 
  except
    ShowMessage('Erro ao criar objeto Word');
  end;
end;
```

**Terceiro:** Você vai precisar definir no seu relatório quais são os campos que serão alterado, como você mesmo disse, será necessário alterar professor, data, nome do treinamento, etc. No documento, coloque um identificador no relatório para o texto a ser substituído, por exemplo:

`Eu, @nomeprofessor, atesto que estou realizando o curso de @nomedocurso na data @data.`

**Quarto:** Depois de ter o modelo pronto, é só alterar e/ou adicionar os campos da seguinte forma:

```
procedure PreencherRelatorio;
var
  vObjWord: variant;
  i, vQtd: integer;
begin
  if not CriarObjetoWord(vObjWord) then
    Exit;
  { para substituir campos }
  vObjWord.Content.Find.Execute(FindText := ´@nomeprofessor´, ReplaceWith := 'Lucas de Souza');
  vObjWord.Content.Find.Execute(FindText := ´@nomedocurso ´, ReplaceWith := 'Lógica de Programação');
  vObjWord.Content.Find.Execute(FindText := ´@data´, ReplaceWith := '21/12/2017');    

  { vai pra última linha }
  vObjWord.Selection.EndKey(wdStory);

  { para adicionar linhas }
  vQtd := vObjWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Count;
  for i := 0 to 10 do
  begin
    vObjWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add(Name := 'Teste');
    vObjWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Item(vQtd + 1).Range.Text := 'Olá: ' + IntToStr(i) + #13;
  end;

end;
```

Esse jeito resolveu o meu problema, espero que resolva o seu.

Comment: Boa tarde Lucas. Acho que não me expressei bem. Esses campos que são alterados apenas com um conteúdo eu já consegui fazer, o problema é a lista de alunos, já que não é pra preencher apenas um aluno e sim toda a lista. Mas obrigada por sua explicação.

Comment: Barbara, eu editei a publicação. Vê se agora te ajuda.